# Programmatically inserting a widget into Wordpress sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been using [this code](https://gist.github.com/tyxla/372f51ea1340e5e643f6b47e2ddf43f2) on PHP 7.0, but decided to upgrade to 7.4 tonight. This code automatically inserts widgets into Wordpress sidebar, but it no longer works.

```
function insert_widget_in_sidebar( $widget_id, $widget_data, $sidebar ) {
// Retrieve sidebars, widgets and their instances
$sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets', array() );
$widget_instances = get_option( 'widget_' . $widget_id, array() );

// Retrieve the key of the next widget instance
$numeric_keys = array_filter( array_keys( $widget_instances ), 'is_int' );
$next_key = $numeric_keys ? max( $numeric_keys ) + 1 : 2;

// Add this widget to the sidebar
if ( ! isset( $sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ] ) ) {
    $sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ] = array();
}
$sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ][] = $widget_id . '-' . $next_key;

// Add the new widget instance
$widget_instances[ $next_key ] = $widget_data;

// Store updated sidebars, widgets and their instances
update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets );
update_option( 'widget_' . $widget_id, $widget_instances );
}
```

From my research, it seems to be a problem with "[]" not initializing arrays anymore.

I've tried every single way I know how, but can't get this to work. I've always initialized arrays with [], so I'm sort of lost.

This is an example of the input data:

```
insert_widget_in_sidebar('recent-posts',array('title' => $recent_posts_title,'number' => $recent_posts_number,'show_date' => $show_date),$sidebar_name);
```

Where $sidebar_name would be, for example, 'right-sidebar'.

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: The code seems to be working fine when tested on local setup. What version of WordPress are you using? Also, where do you call function?

Comment: @Kalimah I’m using the latest version of WP. I’ll post the php errors when I get to my PC. I spent hours trying variations of this code, but it simply does not work on php 7.4

Comment: @Kalimah `Warning: Illegal string offset 'right-sidebar' in` `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array`. It worked perfectly fine in PHP 7.0. 'right-sidebar' is the name of the sidebar where I'm trying to place the widget(s). The function is being called in a plugin I created. I have all of the prerequisites included beforehand (works fine in PHP 7.0).

Comment: @GrafiCode `Warning: Illegal string offset 'right-sidebar' in` `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem by properly initializing the arrays... this is an edited version of the code made for my purposes, but here are the main changes:

```
if ( !isset( $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar] ) ) {
    $sidebars_widgets = array();
    $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar] = array();
}
$sidebars_widgets[$sidebar][] = $widget_id . '-' . '1';

// Add the new widget instance
$widget_instances = array();
$widget_instances[1] = $widget_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code seems no longer working in latest wp version. Widgets are dead... hello blocks!
You can easily add a widget to any of your sidebars using my snipped code, which can be improved:
(the example adds a html widget to the sidebar-2 - put it in a function if needed)

```
// get widget blocks for sidebar-2
$widget_block = get_option('widget_block');
$content = 'azerty';

// check for existing value before processing
$id_exist = array_search(array("content" => $content), $widget_block);
if (!is_numeric($id_exist)) {

    // add a widget block
    $widget_block[] = array("content" => $content);
    update_option('widget_block', $widget_block);

    // get block id
    $new_sidebar2_id = array_search(array("content" => $content), $widget_block);

    // get sidebar-2
    $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

    // check for existing value before processing
    $id_exist = array_search('block-' . $new_sidebar2_id, $sidebars_widgets["sidebar-2"]);

    if (!is_numeric($id_exist)) {

        //update sidebar-2
        $sidebars_widgets["sidebar-2"][] = 'block-' . $new_sidebar2_id;
        wp_set_sidebars_widgets($sidebars_widgets);
    }
}
```